# pin TWO folder shortcuts as separate icons on Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts

pin TWO folder shortcuts as separate icons on Windows 7 taskbar?  I did this all the time on XP

Now, when I drag and drop a folder shortcut to my Windows 7 taskbar, it lumps them all in together.

How can I have each folder shortcut show as its own icon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short version of fix in case these links don't work in the future:

Create a shortcut to the explorer folder on your desktop, then edit the location of the shortcut so that it says "explorer" before the path. You can also change the icon by going to the shortcut --> Change Icon option. Then, pin the shortcut to the start bar.

Do note that since this is a *shortcut* and not an app that you're pinning, when you click the shortcut, the window will open under the main Explorer icon.

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-pin-any-folder-windows-7-taskbar

http://lifehacker.com/5372830/pin-individual-folders-to-the-windows-7-taskbar

Personally, I'm a big fan of using the official pin feature to pin folders to the Explorer app (keeps the start bar clean), but I'm guessing since you're asking specifically how to pin the icon separately, that you've considered that option. But wanted to mention it as an option just in case.

Comment: It's great that you linked to a solution, but you should describe how to do it in your answer and then link at the bottom so that the post is still valid even if lifehacker or 7tutorials goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you like the new task bar, but I HATE it. I use the "Free Launch Bar". It gives you back the old task bar, including a quick-launch equivalent. After you install it, you enable it by right-clicking the taskbar>Toolbar>click Free Launch Bar. It is awesome, imo.

http://www.freelaunchbar.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thought other's might like a *slightly* different method.

1. **Right-Click** the folder you want a shortcut of and click **Send to** > **Desktop (create shortcut)**
2. Find your shortcut on the Desktop and **Right-Click** selecting **Properties**
3. Edit the **Target** field and prepend the path that's already there with *explorer* and put the path in quotes (see below for example)
4. Click **Apply** and **OK**
5. You may now **Right-Click** > **Pin to Taskbar** or drag-and-drop as you would normally

Example Target field (quotes and space between explorer and path matter):

```
explorer "C:\Users\johndoe"
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. You have two folder icons on the taskbar, say Downloads and Pictures. Open both of them and a third folder icon appears showing both folders in it on mouseover.

You can put two shortcuts in the Links folder showing on the taskbar and the same thing happens, without the ugly pinned folders.